# Faraday::SSLError when using archive_link on Enterprise Octokit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-api, octokit

I had 2 Github apps. One for enterprise and one for normal GitHub. I am trying to get the zip file download URL using `Client.archive_link(source_url, format: "zipball")` and it works for the regular GitHub but gives this error on the enterprise:
`Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)):`
Does anyone know what is causing this?

The other functions of the client object from Octokit are working so I don't get why only this one isn't.